# tcolorbox: unset or overrule option "listing side text"

Tags: tcolorbox

I a large file with examples I have boxes where the code and output should
be besides each other, which I get using the option "listing side text".
But there are situations where the code should be above the text (as is
per default). But after the option "listing side text" I cannot return to
this default, whatever I try. I must have overlooked something in the
manual, and I keep overlooking it. So please can someone give me a hint?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
  colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
  colbacklower=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text above}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\tcbset{%
  listing side text,
}

\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text aside}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\tcbset{%
  listing above text,
}

\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text ???}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update:*

After reporting [this issue](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/38), I've received an answer.

`listing side text` is equivalent to `listing and text`+`sidebyside`. If this style is defined globally, something like `listing above text` only changes the first setting, while `sidebyside` remains active. We need to add `sidebyside=false` to avoid it's effect.

As you can see in my previous answer, if styles are applied locally we don't need `sidebyside=false`.

A working version of your code should be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
  colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
  colbacklower=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text above}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\tcbset{%
  listing side text, %<-- = listing and text, sidebyside
}

\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text aside}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\tcbset{%
  listing above text,
  sidebyside=false   %<---- To delete previous `sidebyside`
}

\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text ???}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Other options which include `sidebyside` are: `text side listing`, `listing side text`, `comment side listing`, `listing side comment`.

*Original answer:*

It seems to be a problem with `listing side text` that fixes some parameters that are not overwriten/deleted by `listing above text`, but the problem disappears if you declare these options in `tcblisting` or using particular `newtcblistings` for each option.

Solution with `listing` option in generic `tcblisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
  colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
  colbacklower=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text above}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text aside, listing side text}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{title= Text ???, listing above text}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Solution declaring particular listings for each option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{%
  colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!75!black,
  colbacklower=white,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
}

\newtcblisting{mylisting}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    #1
}

\newtcblisting{sidelisting}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    listing side text,
    #1
}

\newtcblisting{abovelisting}[2][]{
    title=#2,
    listing above text,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mylisting}{Text above}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{mylisting}

\begin{sidelisting}{Text aside}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{sidelisting}

\begin{abovelisting}[colback=blue!5!white, colframe=blue!75!black]{Text ???}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{abovelisting}

\begin{abovelisting}[listing side text]{Text ???}
\LaTeX{} in a Box
\end{abovelisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly. The blue box is not the solution I was looking for. I wanted the _original_ (default) behaviour as shown in box 1 (Text above) back again. Can you provide a solution for that?

Comment: The default behaviour is `listing and text` and not `listing above text` as you used in your code. In any case, it seems to be a problem with `listing side text`. By the moment you'll have to use this option as a particular one in each box if you want to over write it with `listing and text` or `text and listing`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "listing _and_ text", which is not easily found in the manual. I defined VBox and HBox to set the stuff hor/vert. So my problem is solved. Can it be that this behaviour of tcolorbox is bug?

Comment: @Jack I've reported this issue. Let's wait for some comment from the author.

Comment: @Jack I've updated the answer with an `official` solution.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. It would have been nice if some new to tcb could find that in the manual easily. For the moment I have a working solution (H- and VBox) based on your previous answer. I am a bit reluctant to change the  working stuff now (maybe when I grow curious)